# How to build the latest git flow release branch in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, git-flow

I'm trying to set up continuous integration in Jenkins for git flow style development. I thought I would create three jobs to build RPM packages: for master, develop and the latest release branch.

The problem is with the latest release branch, as I'm not sure it is possible to setup builds so that Jenkins polls my git repo, and only does a build if the change ocurrs in the latest release/* branch. Is it more usual for people to clone jobs and hardcore branch names or can what I intend be done?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to see if there is a generic way to build branches in jenkins? (correct me if I am wrong)

If thats what your trying to achieve, you can use parameterized builds. Make the branch name as a parameter.In jenkins configuration for the build, you can specify parameter name as BRANCH and reference that in your git clone command (i am assuming your using execute shell)

git clone -b ${BRANCH}

Now everytime  you build, jenkins will prompt you for the branch name and you can specify values like origin/master or origin/release etc..

Hope this helps

Comment: That is not what I had actually in mind. I would like Jenkins to poll my git repository where branches are named according to this regexp: release/[0-9]+ then if there was a commit to the branch with highest release number, do a build from that. I don't think this is actually possible, I ended up hardcoding the branch name and I have another job which bumps the release number in my jobs. It's slightly more flexible in some ways and probably more correct.